# How do I start an "if" function in shell that requires the user to input between 4-9 parameters

Tags: linux, bash

I needto see if between 4 and 9 arguments were entered at the command line.  Then if so display the first and the third and exit with a code equal to the number of arguments on the command line

Comment: Since this seems semi-arbitrary, have you learned anything about UNIX shells recently that would help you along this path? What have you tried and what were the results?

Comment: Some related reading:  [Positional Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Positional-Parameters), [Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs), [Bash Builtin Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins), [Bourne Builtin Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a homework assignment, so I will give all the bits of the puzzle that you need to solve it.

1. The number of arguments are kept in the special variable `$#`.
2. The third argument is `$3`.
3. To see whether a variable `$var` is between 3 and 19 (inclusively), use

   ```
   if [ "$var" -ge 3 ] && [ "$var" -le 19 ]; then ...; fi
   ```

   where `...` is the action you'd like to take if the statement is 
   *true*.
4. Explicitly exiting from a *script* is done with `exit`.  Explicitly returning from a *function* is done with `return`.  Both of these take an optional exit status.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. I was having trouble wrapping my head around getting the range I was trying to do "$# -eq 4-9" , then I was trying to do it similar to your approach but using the -o flag.

Comment: @user344036 If Kusalananda's answer was helpful to you, it's courteous to mark the answer as "Accepted."